# Verdana different rendering in Chrome and FF

Tags: google-chrome, fonts, frontend, mozilla

Note: this issue is on windows.

I found that text my current website is shown different in Chrome and FF. The font is Verdana. The same word in FF look wider than in Chrome. I could not find the reason, so I start to search site that also use Verdana.

I found [this site](http://www.rosewholesale.com/cheap-online/dresses-c7/) that uses Verdana for side navigation. The links look different in Chrome and FF as well. (Screenshot [in chrome](http://prntscr.com/9zqqm7), [in FF](http://prntscr.com/9zqrr9)).

But then I found [this site](http://www.koovs.com/sbuys-schiffli-shirt-dress-73014.html?from=category-655&skuid=294915) where text is also in Verdana. But on this site text looks the same in Chrome and FF?

Why this happens and how to make the Verdana text look the same in these two browsers.

**UPD:** I added the showcase in [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ditalo/5/edit?html,css,js,console,output). (I thought that it was more real if I gave links to real site where you can see the problem). Open the jsbin file in Chrome and FF, run js and open console. You can see the width of the div with text in FF is 53 and in Chrome - 49.

Comment: Please show proof. A simple check shows idental rendering between FF and Chrome on Windows 7 for me. http://imgur.com/h6JDQnx -- Also, show your research. What have you investigated so far? Did you try a minimal case to find out whether what you're saying is true if you *just* have a single element with styled text in a document? Basically, are you following [the guidelines on asking a good question](/help/how-to-ask) ?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Sorry, but from my previous experience it was better if I shown the real problem. Not represented one. Also I do not understand why screenshots where the width of text block is shown and where it is clear that it is different in the browsers cannot be a proof. However, I added a jsbin snippet where js shows the width of the text block. I think it is enough now.

Comment: if you don't have code, show pictures, and then try to reduce the example to minimal code and add that, too. Remember that you're asking people to spend their own time, which they can probably use better, to help you, so you make sure they don't need to hunt for the information.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans "show pictures" - I show screenshots from FF and Chrome. What's wrong with them? It takes in me 10 sec to open developer tool in FF and Chrome and to see what's happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're scaling the font down to something very tiny, which is [impossible to get right](http://www.rastertragedy.com/): each font engine will do pixel aligning differently, so Firefox, IE, and Chrome will all start to show different metrics the smaller you make things, because they all use different font engines.

Stick to the recommended minimum of 16px and higher and the browsers report the same dimensions; http://jsbin.com/caxasahacu/edit?html,css,js,console,output

(remember that not everyone has eagle-vision. For the vast majority of users, 16px is [pretty much the smallest](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/UseLegibleFontSizes) you can reliably make text before you're forcing people to zoom)

Comment: Strange, I thought this problem is only with Verdana font. When I use other fonts (like Arial) with font size smaller than 16 px it looks the same. Moreover, 15px in Verdana is nearly to 16px in Arial for example. And I see a lot of sites that use font-size smaller than 16px. But it is useful issue to remember about.